# PostgreSQL jsonb_path_query removes result instead of returning null value

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb, jsonpath, set-returning-functions

In an example table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE example (
    id   SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    data JSON NOT NULL );
INSERT INTO example (id, data) VALUES
  (1, '[{"key": "1", "value": "val1"}, {"key": "2", "value": "val2"}]')
, (2, '[{"key": "1", "value": "val1"}]')
, (3, '[{"key": "1", "value": "val1"}, {"key": "2", "value": "val2"}]');
```

I want to query the value field in the data column where key = 2.
The query I'm currently using is this:

```sql
SELECT id,
       jsonb_path_query(
               TO_JSONB(data),
               '$[*] ? (@.key == "2").value'::JSONPATH
           )::VARCHAR AS values
FROM example
```

I would expect the results to be:

| id | values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "val2" |
| 2 | null |
| 3 | "val2" |

But the actual result is:

| id | values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "val2" |
| 3 | "val2" |

Is there a reason why the null output of `jsonb_path_query()` is omitted?
How do I get it to behave the way I'm expecting?

Comment: If you want to use JSON path, then why is your column not defined as `jsonb`? Then you can also get rid of the casting. `jsonb` is the recommended data type for JSON values anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `jsonb_path_query_first()` if you want the result of the path expression:

```
SELECT id,
       jsonb_path_query_first(data, '$[*] ? (@.key == "2").value') AS values
FROM example
```

Note that this returns a `jsonb` value. If you want a `text` value, use:

```
jsonb_path_query_first(data, '$[*] ? (@.key == "2").value') #>> '{}
```

Comment: Hi, what does `#>> '{}'` do? Or how does it work?  I am trying to find but haven't been successful.  Also, what is difference between `jsonb_path_query` AND `jsonb_path_query_first` ?  Can you please explain.  Also, how do I convert value to be the type like float etc., when using jsonpath in the query? Thanks

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thankyou for your answer. I recently had a very similar problem to the original poster. Even simplifying to remove the filter expression, I found that `jsonb_path_query` removed rows that would have null values from my returned data. The answer explains how to solve the problem but doesn't explain why the original doesn't work. Perhaps my understanding of what `jsonb_path_query` does is off. Could you expand at all? Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

Scalar function *processes* a value and it can nullify it, but a [set-returning function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-SET) *generates* values, so it can end up not generating one at all. As [already suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67771682/5298879), you can use the scalar function

```sql
SELECT id, jsonb_path_query_first(data::jsonb, '$[*]?(@.key=="2").value')
FROM example;
```

Alternatively, you can keep the SRF, Set-Returning Function [`jsonb_path_query()`**`→ setof jsonb`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#id-1.5.8.22.5.11.2.2.19.1.1.1) by wrapping it in a [scalar subquery](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-SCALAR-SUBQUERIES) or replacing its implicit inner join. Both will indicate lack of generated values with a null, but the latter can also still spawn and return multiple: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/3Bt6uQaL)

```sql
SELECT id,(SELECT jsonb_path_query(data::jsonb,'$[*]?(@.key=="2").value')LIMIT 1)
FROM example;

SELECT id, values
FROM example LEFT JOIN jsonb_path_query(data::jsonb, '$[*]?(@.key=="2").value') 
                       AS srf(values) 
             ON true;
```

Row 2 wasn't generating any rows in that function, which is why you didn't see it - there was no row to have a `null` in. Select section is [not a normal place](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-SET:%7E:text=Set%2Dreturning%20functions%20in%20the%20select%20list%20are%20always%20evaluated%20as%20though%20they%20are%20on%20the%20inside%20of%20a%20nested%2Dloop%20join%20with%20the%20rest%20of%20the%20FROM%20clause) for an SRF - when applied there, it ends up pushed down to `from` section to be `inner joined` with. And `inner join` with an empty set, is an empty set. That, combined with [implicit join](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-join.html) beahaviour, is why you can read:

- `SELECT srf();` as an actual `SELECT b.x FROM srf() AS b(x);`
- `SELECT a.id, srf() FROM a;` meaning `SELECT a.id, b.x FROM a, srf() AS b(x);`
- `SELECT a.id, b.x FROM a, srf(a.v) AS b(x);` and `SELECT a.id, srf(a.v) FROM a;` actually meaning:

  `SELECT a.id, b.x FROM a INNER JOIN srf(a.v) AS b(x) ON true;`

This `INNER JOIN` threw out your `id`s that didn't have result-generating `data`. `LEFT JOIN` won't.

---

Another illustration with a more obvious `generate_series()` "give me this many rows" SRF: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/9_suFaY1)

```sql
create table table1(id smallserial, how_many_to_generate int);
insert into table1(how_many_to_generate) values (1),(0),(2),(0),(1);

--no rows for the 2nd and 4th entry where `how_many_to_generate` is 0
--on the other hand, the 3rd entry requested and received two rows
select id, how_many_to_generate, generate_series(1, how_many_to_generate)
from table1;
-- id | how_many_to_generate | generate_series
------+----------------------+-----------------
--  1 |                    1 |               1
--  3 |                    2 |               1
--  3 |                    2 |               2
--  5 |                    1 |               1
```

Comment: Super comprehensive answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As per [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH-OPERATORS) the filter acts as `WHERE` condition

> When defining the path, you can also use one or more filter expressions that work similar to the WHERE clause in SQL. A filter expression begins with a question mark and provides a condition in parentheses:

I managed to achieve what you're looking for using the `LATERAL` and a `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT id,
         *
FROM example left join 
LATERAL jsonb_path_query(
        TO_JSONB(data),
        '$[*] ? (@.key == "2").value'::JSONPATH) 
    on true;
```

Result

```
 id | id |                              data                              | jsonb_path_query 
----+----+----------------------------------------------------------------+------------------
  1 |  1 | [{"key": "1", "value": "val1"}, {"key": "2", "value": "val2"}] | "val2"
  2 |  2 | [{"key": "1", "value": "val1"}]                                | 
  3 |  3 | [{"key": "1", "value": "val1"}, {"key": "2", "value": "val2"}] | "val2"
(3 rows)
```