# How to duplicate rows when selecting from table

Tags: postgresql

It it possible to duplicate rows when selecting data from postgres?

For example, given the following data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE some_table (
    id serial not null,
    multiply int not null
);

INSERT INTO some_table (multiply)
VALUES (1), (2), (3);
```

The data added to the table looks like:

| id | multiply |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |

When selecting the data, I want to duplicate each row by the number in the `multiply` column, so the results would look like:

| id | multiply |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 |

Is this possible?

The closest I've managed to get is using `array_fill` along with `unnest`, which generates the desired number of duplicate rows, however only a single column is returned

```sql
SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY_FILL(t, ARRAY(t.multiply])) FROM some_table t;
```

| unnest |
| --- |
| (1,1) |
| (2,2) |
| (2,2) |
| (3,3) |
| (3,3) |
| (3,3) |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a set-returning function [`generate_series(1,multiply)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html). It generates a series of numbers from `1` to the value of `multiply`, by default in steps of `1`: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/KzAbuawx)

```sql
select *, generate_series(1,multiply) from some_table;
```

| id | multiply | generate_series |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 |

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75716124/5298879)'s more on how that works: by placing it in the `select` list rather than the `from` section, you're effectively producig a [`lateral join on true`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL), so this function gets re-evaluated once for every row present in `some_table`, and the resulting rows get matched to the row they were generated for.

It's good to remember that due to the nature of this, if you set multiply to `0`, it'll hide that row, because the resulting join will be between something and nothing. You can secure yourself against that as well as accidental negative upper limit by adding [`greatest(multiply,1)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST):

```sql
select *, generate_series(1,greatest(multiply,1)) from some_table;
```

Comment: Thank you! I had looked at this function but gave up on it, thinking that I couldnt pass in extra data (extra columns that I want to be duplicated), so didnt think it would be suitable. But you're example shows how to do just that; select the columns you want, _then_ the function. This is exactly what I was after, Thanks